# Is Vaadin 7 compatible with Spring Boot 2.x?

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin7

I have an old Vaadin 7 application, and I'm trying to upgrade the Spring Boot version from 1.5.22.RELEASE to 2.0.9.RELEASE. I keep running into errors. Should this even work? I can't find any documentation about the version compatibility.

Edit:

The errors are along the lines of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver` due to the various API changes between the Spring versions.

The official [Vaadin Spring Boot add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadin-spring-boot) 1.2.x branch that is meant to be used with Vaadin 7 only seems to support Spring Boot 1.5. The 3.x branch of the add-on for current Vaadin 8 versions apparently works with both, but those changes haven't been backported to the older branch and the newer branch doesn't work with Vaadin 7. Applying the [Spring Boot Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) to my project itself doesn't do the trick thanks to the add-on incompatibility.

Comment: **What** errors? Please be specific.

Comment: I didn't consider those relevant since the question is about expected compatibility rather than how to get past the errors, but I can try to remember to add something next week (just finishing my workday).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not, Vaadin 7 is only compatible up to Spring Boot 1.5. If you want to use Spring Boot 2.x, you have three options:

- Upgrade your project to use Vaadin 8 (compatible with both Spring Boot 1.5 and 2.x), see [migration guide](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/migration/migrating-to-vaadin8) for details. In most cases this is fairly straightforward with the help of the compatibility classes. It's probably a good idea to do the Vaadin version upgrade first, and only upgrade Spring Boot version after the application is already running on Vaadin 8 (that way it's easier to figure out which upgrade to blame if there are any problems). However, it should be noted that the free support of Vaadin 8 will end in February 2022 already, although the commercial extended support will be available for 10 more years after that.
- Create a new Vaadin 14 project (only compatible with Spring Boot 2.x, the starter app generated by [start.vaadin.com](https://start.vaadin.com/) is Spring Boot based by default), purchase a Vaadin subscription that includes [Multiplatform Runtime](https://vaadin.com/multiplatform-runtime) which allows you to use Vaadin 7 classes from within Vaadin 14, and insert your old views into the new project with the help of the MPR wrappers. Remember to leave out your old Vaadin 7 Spring add-on, and to use the new one that is wired through Flow Servlet instead. This option requires a bit more initial effort (and the subscription), but gives you a leg up to continue converting your project to a pure Vaadin 14 version later on.
- Upgrade your project fully to Vaadin 14 (or higher, but that's the newest LTS version at the moment). The [migration guide](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/1-migrating-v8-v10) is from Vaadin 8 up, so you might need to consult the Vaadin 7 to Vaadin 8 migration guide as well for some features. This is a significantly bigger jump than from Vaadin 7 to Vaadin 8 since the whole client-side handling was rewritten after Vaadin 8, but gives you right away access to the newer bells and whistles, you'll have several more years of free support available, and upgrading from Vaadin 14 to the next LTS version in turn should be a smaller step again.